# How to capture client url in apigee?

Tags: api, cross-domain, apigee

How can I capture client url in apigee

I am using javascript in  'PreFlow' of 'Proxy endpoint'

context.setVariable("request.header.host",context.getVariable('request.header.host'))
context.setVariable("request.header.origin",context.getVariable('request.header.origin'))

I do not get any value return for 'request.header.origin' and for 'request.header.host' i get the proxy end point

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the url which is sent from client right?

If I understand correctly, try the code below:

In **Proxy Endpoints** you can use `context.getVariable("proxy.url");`